# Die Unterschiede zwischen „erwägen“, „überlegen“, „berücksichtigen“ und „bedenken“

Tags: difference, meaning

Bitte könntet ihr die nuancierten Unterschiede zwischen *erwägen, überlegen, berücksichtigen* und *bedenken* erklären? Oder mir entsprechende Beispiele geben?

Das Wörterbuch, das ich benutze, übersetzt sie jeweils als:

- *to consider*
- *to put over sep / to think over, consider / to think,
  reflect (haben)*
- *to take into consideration*
- *to consider; (überlegen)
  think over*

Answer (score 8):

*Erwägen* ist ähnlich zu *abwägen* und entstammt ursprünglich dem Verb *wiegen.* Du kannst dir also eine Balkenwaage vorstellen, mit der du verschiedene Optionen gegeneinander abwiegst/erwägst. Oder aber du hast nur eine Option, die du sorgfältig wiegen/erwägen musst, um alle Konsequenzen zu erfassen.

> Ich erwäge gerade, ob wir Hans auch einladen sollen. (Einerseits wollen wir ihn gar nicht da haben, andererseits wollen wir ihn nicht ganz ausschließen, weil er irgendwie dazugehört.)

*Überlegen* beschreibt das klassische Nachdenken. (Einige Politiker würden hier »ergebnisoffen« dazusagen.) Du hast also eine Idee, ein Vorschlag oder eine These, und überlegst ganz grundsätzlich, was dabei passieren oder nicht passieren kann. Es hat keine Tendenz in keine Richtung; weder muss das Überlegte angenommen werden noch muss es verworfen werden.

> Ich überlege gerade, ob wir Hans auch einladen sollen. (Er gehört nicht zu dem Kreis, den man einladen *muss* um sie nicht zu verprellen, hätte es keinen Schaden, ihn trotzdem einzuladen.)

*Berücksichtigen* würde man verwenden, wenn ein Einwand kommt, an den man noch nicht gedacht hat. Diesen Einwand nicht zu berücksichtigen wäre eine sehr schlechte Idee und wird deswegen meist gar nicht erwogen. Man muss aber vielleicht auf Konsequenzen vorbereitet sein.

> Ich berücksichtige gerade, dass wir Hans noch einladen wollten. (Ich habe es vorher vergessen, jetzt schreibe ich schnell die Einladung.)

Zum Wort *bedenken* gibt es auch die *Bedenken,* die es meist zu bedenken gilt. *Bedenken* als Substantiv beschreibt Einwände, die andere Leute gegen die eigene Idee haben. Manche Politiker tun wenig anderes, als ständig mit Bedenken um sich zu werfen. *Bedenken* ist in seinen Nuancen ähnlich *erwägen,* wobei *bedenken* eher selten in der Ich-Form verwendet wird.

> Bedenkst du bitte, dass wir Hans noch einladen wollten? (Jetzt hast du Idiot Hans schon wieder vergessen!)

Comment: Klasse Erklärung und vor allem gute Beispiele!

Answer (score 1):

Wie du bereits bemerkt hast liegt der Unterschied in kleinen Nuancen bzw. im Sprachgebrauch und Kontext!

- ***erwägen:*** in Betracht ziehen oder sorgfältig durchdenken; prüfen

  Es wird oft benutzt um zu sagen, dass man etwas nicht ausschließen möchte und benutzt, wenn man es benötigt.

  Beispiele und weitere Infos zum Gebrauch [hier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/erw%C3%A4gen)
- ***überlegen (sich überlegen):*** mit einem bestimmten Ziel nachdenken, in Gedanken versinken oder etwas überdenken, aber auch grundsätzlich nachdenken (ohne ein festes oder vorgegebenes Ziel oder Gedankenrichtung).

  [Anwendung:](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BCberlegen) es sich überlegen; es sich anders überlegen ("sich für was anderes entscheiden"); nicht lange überlegen; sich etwas reiflich überlegen.
- ***berücksichtigen:*** z.B. bei seinen Planungen und Handlungen beachten, in seine Überlegungen mit einbeziehen, aber auch im Sinne von auf jemanden, etwas Rücksicht nehmen; jemanden oder etwas beachten; jemanden oder etwas in Betracht ziehen (In diesem Sinne kann gleichbedeutend zu erwägen). Gegenwort: missachten!
  *beachten* käme hier als Synonym in Frage!

  Beispiele und weitere Infos [hier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ber%C3%BCcksichtigen).
- ***bedenken:*** bei seinen Überlegungen berücksichtigen (Vergleichbar mit erwägen und überlegen); sich gedanklich mit etwas beschäftigen; (sich bedenken) etwas für sich überlegen; aber auch jemandem etwas zukommen lassen oder etwas schenken.

  Beispiele und zusätzliche Informationen findest du [hier](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/bedenken)

Comment: Danke schön! (Und auch für den vorgeschlagen Änderungsvorschlag. :)) I've got a better gist of it now.